# Re-authenticate user before submitting the form in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a requirement like re-authenticate the user on button click.

Consider the user is trying to save the list form and on click of save, a dialog box asks for username and password. Then we should validate the username and password, and if it matches we submit the form to list or else not.

Its a SharePoint online site.

Comment: How do you plan to validate the credentials? Have you implemented a custom membership provider? You can't just force logout the user, they will lose all their work.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be the following:

1. Inject JavaScript code in the `New` form. This can be done by editing the list form in SharePoint Designer, or by adding the code in the master page (it would first check the current URL) or by adding a custom action in the list.
2. The JavaScript would delete all cookies (including authentication cookies). You can use code like the one proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/179514/3439544.

Note: this won't work for all other means you can add an item. For instance won't work for the Quick Edit mode, for addition with client API, etc.

Comment: Thank you. But once i cleared all the cookies and login again, the form data will reset.